# Distinct multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select the SQL Server datatype and name, but it have columns replicate, this is my SQL:

```
with typesum
as
(
    select sc.xtype,sc.[length],st.name
    from syscolumns sc,systypes st
    where sc.xtype=st.xtype
    group by sc.xtype,sc.[length],st.name
)
select distinct tsa.xtype,tsb.name,tsb.[length] 
from typesum tsa left join typesum tsb
on tsa.xtype=tsb.xtype
```

It has many replicate data.

And I use another way:

```
select distinct (sc.xtype,st.name) from syscolumns sc
left join systypes st
on sc.xtype=st.xtype
group by sc.xtype,st.name
```

It doesn't work.

My question is: how can I distinct multiple columns by distinct one columns and get the unique data?An result has 10 columns,and i want to distinct column 1 as standard, and other columns data should be deleted.

For example:

```
1         1
1         1
2         2
2         2
```

the result is:

```
1         1
2         2
```

maybe sample sql can solve is better.Thank you.

Comment: What does the 'It doesn't work.' mean? You have wrong parentheses in the last query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need both `group by` and `distinct`

Either

```
select distinct sc.xtype,st.name 
from syscolumns sc
left join systypes st
on sc.xtype=st.xtype
```

or

```
select sc.xtype,st.name 
from syscolumns sc
left join systypes st
on sc.xtype=st.xtype
group by sc.xtype,st.name
```

should both work

Comment: select distinct sc.xtype,st.name 
should i understand like this:select distinct (sc.xtype,st.name) or like this:select (distinct sc.xtype),st.name

Comment: @Dolphin `SELECT DISTINCT` applies to all selected values.

Comment: When i want to select more columns like:select sc.name,sc.xtype,st.name,st.[length]
from syscolumns sc left join systypes st
on sc.xtype=st.xtype
group by st.name,sc.xtype,sc.name,st.[length];   and how to distinct the st.name? I want the result st.name to be unique,and other data could be delete.

Comment: I don't understand your request. Could you give before and after samples of data?

Comment: I just want to know how to find unique data from multipul columns by one column.For example:col1: 1 2 3,col2:1 4 5,col3: 2 6 7.And the select result should be:col1:............Oh,i know.......,i want to distinct col1 replicate data 1,but the computer can't decison should choose 1 2 3 or 1 4 5.So that could not be possible,is this?

Comment: @dolphin Exactly. You could use `MIN(col2)` to choose the lowest one, for example